# Q&A Database Schema

Tags: database-design

Need suggestions for a Q&A database design that I will use to interview small business owners. Below is a screenshot of the project and the tables that I came up with. Wanted to know which table should I add the introduction, video and audio urls to?

[image]

```
[People Table]
id
first_name
last_name
job_title
company
photo_url

[Questions Table]
id
question

[Answers Table]
id
person_id
question_id
answer
order_no
```

Comment: What are the video and audio urls for? Would it be accurate to say that each series of questions and answers for a particular person represents an "interview"?

Comment: Correct! each series of Q&A is an "Interview". The video or audio url is optional. A person can have either a text, video or audio interview. So video and audio will show only if text interview part is empty

Comment: Thanks. There's more questions I could ask, but to save time I just made some assumptions and answered. Let me know if my assumptions are way off, then I can modify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some details of your application that could change this model, but hopefully it's enough to get started.

[image: Database model]

Defining an Interviews entity is useful because you can store data that is associated with the Interview itself, for example when the interview happened and who the interviewer was.

There are three types of Interviews here: TextInterviews, VideoInterviews, and AudioInterviews. Since the question-answer pairs only apply to TextInterviews (assumption), the foreign key is to this table.

Each question has up to one answer (assumption). Because of this, the Questions and Answers *could* be combined into a QuestionAnswers table, although it doesn't have to.

Comment: Can I add video_url and audio_url in the "Interviews" table to make it simpler?

Comment: Yes, but your requirement of  "A person can have either a text, video or audio interview [exclusively]" wouldn't be enforced by the database. In that case, there would only be one Interviews table and no child tables. Any data that applies to only one type of interview would be present for every interview. In the scope of this question, that only means an audio_url, video_url, and the Questions' foreign key to Interviews. The list of data that applies to only some interviews will  probably grow, which will lead to many columns that are always null for Interviews of a particular implicit type.

Comment: We're talking about the problem of representing inheritance, which this stackoverflow question addresses: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3579462/3816779. The simpler approach you're suggesting refers to "Single Table Inheritance" in the linked answer. The one I'm suggesting refers to "Class Table Inheritance".